# Unused Google App Engine instance exceeding quota

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I'm running a Java server on Google App Engine. It seems that the GAE account is using up the 9 free instance hours that come with GAE backend instances, but so far I've mostly been running the server on localhost while in development (with only a handful of live deployments just to test the deployment process). Why are instance hours being consumed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What kind of scaling do you have in your project? Basic, manual or automatic?

**edit:**
As you've since indicated you're using manual scaling:

> Manual Scaling: A service with manual scaling **runs continuously**,
>   allowing you to perform complex initialization and rely on the state
>   of its memory over time.

This means that your handful of live deployments probably has at least one in manual scaling mode, which causes your problem

Comment: I have integrated Firebase with GAE, and as such enabled manual scaling as described in this tutorial: https://cloud.google.com/solutions/mobile/firebase-app-engine-android-studio#configuring_the_app_engine_backend_to_use_manual_scaling

Answer (score 0):

Even if this is quite an old question and you probably figured this out already, here is the easiest solution: replacing `manual-scaling` section with a `basic-scaling` one.

Your `appengine-web.xml` will look like the one below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
   <application>myApplicationId</application>
   <version>1</version>
   <threadsafe>true</threadsafe>
   <basic-scaling>
     <max-instances>1</max-instances>
     <idle-timeout>10m</idle-timeout>
   </basic-scaling>
   <system-properties>
     <property name="java.util.logging.config.file" value="WEB-INF/logging.properties" />
   </system-properties>
</appengine-web-app>
```

This means that, through `basic-scaling`, your application will have maximum 1 running instance, and will be passivated (so you will not pay for it) after 10 minutes

Comment: While this may work for a quick test during development it's not OK for longer tests or production. From the tutorial being followed (mentioned in comments): "To use Firebase with App Engine standard environment, you must use manual scaling. This is because Firebase uses background threads to listen for changes and App Engine standard environment allows long-lived background threads only on manually scaled backend instances."